# Selenium/Python/Xpath and getting text between react-text comments

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following HTML snippet and discovered how to get to the text (a date and time) with the following Xpath in Chrome.  However, with Selenium, using find_element_by_xpath doesn't work because it needs to grab an element.  It also doesn't work if I get the Xpath to capture the react-text comment.  Also, tried grabing the top div tag and then doing an [element].text, but that is not seeing the date/time text.  How can I grab that date/time so it is usable in my Selenium script.  Thank you very much.

//div[@data-list-index='0']/div/div/div/div[@aria-colindex = '8']/div/span[2]/following-sibling::text()

[image]

Comment: Questions must provide a [mcve] and code should always be plain text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('your_website_url')
parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-list-index='0']/div/div/div/div[@aria-colindex='8']/div/span[2]")
date_time_text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent;", parent_element)
print(date_time_text)
```

To ByPass or Avoid UnicodeError

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('your_website_url')
parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-list-index='0']/div/div/div/div[@aria-colindex='8']/div/span[2]")

date_time_text = driver.execute_script("""
    const parent = arguments[0];
    let text = '';
    for (const node of parent.childNodes) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            text += node.textContent.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ''); // Exclude non-ASCII characters
        }
    }
    return text.trim();
""", parent_element)

print(date_time_text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mahboob! I tried the code and I am currently getting the following error when executing: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2731' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>. I looke up the \u2732 code and it is the "heavy asterisk" . For some reason it doesn't like that. Is there some way to bypass that "heavy asterisk" and skip to just the date/time text? Thank you very much! @Mahboob Nur

Comment: @SAB15 sure. I have modified the code for you.